# Pro and in-app version of the same app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

We have in the AppStore a free app which has a PRO in-app purchase. 
The in-app it's the usual appId of form `com.our.appid.pro` and purchasing it sets a boolean in userdefaults which enables or disables specific features in the app. It's all working fine.

However, I have the requirement to create a version which is PRO as soon as you download it from the AppStore. It would be equivalent to a free version with the in-app purchase already bought.

My question is, what is the most convenient way to do this ? Do I simply change the appid and force that boolean to YES for the purchased state and reupload it again as a different app ? I guess it cannot be done without having another app/appid ( that's why in-app purchases were implemented in the first place ... ).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, If you want to submit an app with fully featured app including the In App Purchase Functionality of your older version, then just change the bundle Id of your new app.

Make a new app on iTunes with a different app name and all features without In App Purchase for your those extra functionality of your older version.

Then you will be good to go.

Another option is that if you don't want to go for the PRO version of the app, then remove In App Purchase from your free version and increase the price tier of your free version and submit your app again without In App Purchase.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You should also mention that the OP will need to create two almost-identical targets in his Xcode project and one needs to include a constant (like `-DPRO_VERSION=1`) so he can use conditional complication to remove the in-app purchase code.

Comment: @Manthan I thought this is the only option :(

Comment: @trojanfoe Do i really need to remove the code itself ? I mean I could set that bool to true at first launch based on the appid so the in-app purchase UI wouldn't appear at all, the app recognizing itself as 'pro'.

Comment: @Templar No you don't **have** to, but you're going to need to know if you're building the pro version or not, so you need the constant set in the build settings, so you might as well use it to remove unnecessary code.